# How can I fix the error message: symbol lookup error

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, ide

I tried to install codeblocks, the IDE for c++. I was getting continuously error messages. I thus updated many times and reinstalled many times codeblocks.

I downloaded `codeblocks` `tar` file from the codeblocks webpage and after the file extraction I installed it with the command:

```
sudo dpkg -i *17.12*.deb
```

The installation seemed to work properly. I was then trying to open codeblocks. Here is the error message that I got:

```
codeblocks: error while loading shared libraries: libwx_gtk2u_aui-3.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Thereafter I tried to install what was missing:

```
sudo apt-get install libwx
```

It did not change much.

I first uninstalled and removed codeblocks:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge codeblocks
```

After I got other error messages I tried:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Then I got the following message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 codeblocks : Depends: codeblocks-common (= 16.01+dfsg-2.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: xterm
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install codeblocks-common
```

which I removed soon,

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge codeblocks-common
```

Then I updated:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I got this message:

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Then I tried to fix some other problem:

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-audio-dev-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list
```

And then updated:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then I did the following:

```
sudo dpkg -P --force-all shared-mime-info
```

I got:

```
libgtk-3-0:amd64 depends on shared-mime-info.
 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64 depends on shared-mime-info.
 libgtk2.0-0:amd64 depends on shared-mime-info.
 evince depends on shared-mime-info.
```

I installed what seemed necessary:

```
sudo apt-get install shared-mime-info
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This lasted kind of long, but I think it ended successfully. I then tried to install again:

```
sudo apt-get install codeblocks-common
sudo apt install codeblocks
```

It ended without any error message.

Then, in view of launching codeblocks via the terminal, I typed codeblocks in the command line to get the error:

```
codeblocks: symbol lookup error: codeblocks: undefined symbol: _ZN24IncrementalSelectListDlgD1Ev
```

When I click at the shortcut for `codeblocks`, it does not open, i.e., it tries some seconds then it stops.

What is the problem here ? How can I fix it ?

These are the data of the Ubuntu version I have:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"
```

Comment: Edit question, to show us what you do to get the error.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to open codeblocks, either by clicking on the icon (it does not open), or by typing codeblocks in the terminal which gives me the error which I typed in the question.

Comment: **Edit question**, to show us what you do to get the error.

Comment: Could you tell us exactly how you installed Codeblocks? Normally an error like this would mean a broken package and/or missing dependencies.

Comment: I edited the question. Thanks for reading it and eventually giving a feedback.

Comment: Did you install the contrib-plugins package? The download page notes that incompatible with Ubuntu. Presuming you didn't, it really sounds like more of it has become incompatible with Ubuntu... if that's the case, you'll probably have to build from source. (I'm not posting this as an answer as it's a guess, and I'm hoping someone with some first-hand experience shows up and writes a real answer).

Comment: Many thanks. I do not recall to have installed it, I guess I didn't. It is astonishing that nobody could help me, i.e. nobody posted an answer.